# Why doesn't the generating function for Fibonacci match its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, characteristic-functions

For Fibonacci numbers I usually see generating function $\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$ or $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$ depending on initial terms.

But the denominator, $1-x-x^2$, seems different from the usual characteristic polynomial $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$. It doesn't appear to be a simple multiplication by $-1$ either since the $x$ term is negative in both cases.

I'm asking this simpler question because I am getting strange and unexpected results over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243579/how-can-i-finish-up-my-generating-function-for-second-degree-recurrences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write down the recurrence relation for Fibonacci numbers and the consequence it has on the generating function, you will immediately notice that $1-x-x^2$ is just the characteristic polynomial of the Fibonacci sequence *with its coefficients written in the opposite order*, i.e. $x^2\,p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ with $p(x)$ being $x^2-x-1$.

**Addendum**: such "reversal" process has an interesting side-effect: the radius of convergence of the generating function is exactly the reciprocal of the modulus of the largest root of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to lead to inverse roots, by chance, would it? It would explain my utterly bizarre results in the other question.

Comment: @user438407: of course it has reciprocal roots: it is a side effect of the relation I have just written down, $q(x)=x^2\,p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$.

Comment: It may be obvious to others but I do not see the connection -- would you be able to expand with a more explicit example of what you mean and why the roots are reciprocal of the characteristic polynomial's?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$, it is trivial that $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is a root of $x^2\,p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$!

Comment: More specifically, in my other question I found that the solution to $F_n = bF_{n-1} + aF_{n-2}$ is of form $F_n = \alpha (1/R)^n + \beta (1/r)^n$ where $r, R$ are the roots of $1-bx-ax^2 = 0$, but normally the characteristic polynomial is considered $x^2-bx-a = 0$ which actually implies closed form of $F_n = \alpha (R)^n + \beta (r)^n$ or something.

Comment: I don't see why that's trivial nor why that must be true

Comment: @user438407: If $p(\alpha)=0$ and $q(x)=x^2\,p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, $q(x)$ evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ equals $\frac{1}{\alpha^2} p(\alpha)=0$, hence $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is a root of $q(x)$.

Comment: Sorry for not being a genius, man. Is the 'holy goodness' really necessary?

Comment: No, you're right, sorry. Removed.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with that trick; so it would seem that reversing the coefficients of a degree $d$ polynomial $p(x)$ is $q(x) = x^d p(1/x)$ -- so if we have $p(R) = 0$ then $R = 1/x$ gives us $x = 1/R$, or $q(1/R) = (1/R)^d p(R) = 0$, so $1/R$ is a root of the coefficient-reversed polynomial.

Comment: (Just writing it out loud so I understand it, I know it's basically the same as what you said) Thanks